# Email validatior Javascript

Tags: angularjs, regex

Here is my javascript code

```
 $scope.isValidEmailAddress = function(emailAddress) {
            // var pattern = new RegExp(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/);
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
```

When i validate below email it will return true but this is not, I need to validate this type of email

**`rohan@yahoo.co.in.in`**

It should be invalid email

Comment: Please explain what it is which makes the address invalid. I get the impression that you mean the doubled top-level domain, but I am not sure. Providing more sample input with desired result might be helpful.

Comment: [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Updated as per comment.

If you want to make it possible to add up to two top level domain names you can make the second domain optional.

```
$scope.isValidEmailAddress = function(emailAddress) {
    // Same regex as before but an additional TLD regex has been added.
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.([a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}\.)?[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

Comment: But in case email address is like this : **rohan@yahoo.co.in** it is giving false value.

Comment: Do you only want to allow a maximum of two dot characters after the @ symbol?

Comment: @shiva There was a typo. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Get the regexp from email method of jquery validate plugin:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js